# Issue while build JasperServer with PostgreSQL Database

Tags: java, css, jasperserver

I am trying to customize the installation of JasperServer.

I have downloaded the source. I have deployed successfully using MySQL database. I want to use PostgreSQL and remove the MySQL database. When I do that it does not work. I tried steps mention in Build Guide.

But Tomcat does not start as deployment descriptor has details of MySQL database. I changed the content to PostgreSQL. Then it worked but now it is not uploading the css and showing the weird view.

Please check with image how it shows.![This is the login page when I deploy the jasperserver][1]

Please help if anyone have done it successfully..

Thanks.....

Error on tomcat..

INFO: Server startup in 9759 ms
2011-11-14 17:15:49,647  WARN FileBufferedOutputStream,Finalizer:237 - Error while deleting the temp
orary file
2011-11-14 17:15:49,650  WARN FileBufferedOutputStream,Finalizer:237 - Error while deleting the temp
orary file
2011-11-14 17:15:49,650  WARN FileBufferedOutputStream,Finalizer:237 - Error while deleting the temp
orary file
2011-11-14 17:15:49,651  WARN FileBufferedOutputStream,Finalizer:237 - Error while deleting the temp
orary file
2011-11-14 17:15:49,651  WARN FileBufferedOutputStream,Finalizer:237 - Error while deleting the temp
orary file
2011-11-14 17:15:49,652  WARN FileBufferedOutputStream,Finalizer:237 - Error while deleting the temp
orary file

2011-11-14 17:15:49,652  WARN FileBufferedOutputStream,Finalizer:237 - Error while deleting the temp
orary file
2011-11-14 17:15:49,653  WARN FileBufferedOutputStream,Finalizer:237 - Error while deleting the temp
orary file

Comment: Please show us any error messages that is visible in the Tomcat logs

Comment: Please check the content of tomcat.. Thanks..

Comment: This is the warning:2011-11-11 18:47:11,736  WARN FileBufferedOutputStream,Finalizer:237 - Error while deleting the temp
orary file

Comment: I am sorry. I edited the question but dont know its not showing the updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make changes in file "decoratorCommonImports.jsp"

Provide direct path of theme folder like

" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

replace above line with following one..

Thanks..